# t3xutils Call to a member function getType() on a non-object when i try to upload a extension

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions

today we tried to upload a new version of our extension by using t3xutils.

Our approach:

```
wget ...
chmod +x t3xutils.phar
./t3xutils.phar upload <TER_USER> <TER_PASSWORD> <EXT_KEY> <MESSAGE> <PATH_TO_EXTENSION>
```

We got the following Error with all extensions:
SOAP-Error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object

The message is directly returned from server after calling the function `$this->client->__soapCall('uploadExtension', ...`

Can anyone reproduce the error? Is there an error on the TER-Server from TYPO3?

Comment: Did it work before? If yes, try asking on TYPO3 slack, they might be able to tell if there was some update to the TER servers. Also which version of t3xutils are you using?

Comment: Yes, it worked before. I will try asking on TYPO3 slack. Thank you.